# React object as useEffect dependency triggers callback on every render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a relatively simple React hook to debounce a value. The only twist is that I want to provide a callback which gets triggered whenever the debounced value changes. I'm aware that I could just have another useEffect inside `App` which listens for changes on `debouncedValue`, but I'd like to integrate this behavior into the reusable hook.

```
const useDebounce = (value, delay, { onChange }) => {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
      onChange(value);
    }, delay);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [value, delay, onChange]);

  return debouncedValue;
};

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const debouncedValue = useDebounce(value, 750, { onChange: (value) => console.log(value) });

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: 50 }}>
      <input value={value} onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)} />
      <p>{value}</p>
      <p>{debouncedValue}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now to the issue I have is that the `onChange` fires twice for every debounce. Apparently the `onChange` callback must be part of the dependency array of `useEffect`, even if I don't care when it updates. But this creates the problem than on every render a new object for `{ onChange: (value) => console.log(value) }` gets created therefore reference equality thinks the `useEffect` dependency has changed. I could just create the object outside of my component, but that would also complicate the API of my hook.

So, my question: what is the easiest way to solve this problem? Ideally without pulling in any 3rd party packages. The fix I can think of would be to write a custom useEffect hook that does deep comparisons, but I hope someone can point me to a simpler solution.

Comment: You can put the onChange function in a useCallback in App so it won't change every render.

Comment: @mins that would work. But again, I can only do that outside of the hook, right? Since inside the hook `useCallback` also requires `onChanges` as a dependency.

Comment: That is correct, since you don't know what values in the callback should be available through closure you have to use `useCallback` in the component that passes the callback function.